# Google Sheets formula to check if string contains ALL unsorted characters in another string (Not App Script)?

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula

I need a Google Sheets native formula (not App Script function) that return true if all characters in string B exist in string A.

For example, if A = ‘CDEFGH’

- If B = ‘EDX’ —> Match = False (character X is not in string A)
- If B = ‘HCE’  —> Match = True (Characters H, C, and E are all in string A)

Note the following:

- The characters in B can be in any order and are not necessarily contiguous - I need to check for the presence of ALL (not any) of B’s characters (in any order) are present in string A.
- I know how to do this in App Script but it is too slow for my application as I need to call this function thousands of times.  So the solution has to be using Google Sheets native built-in functions excluding App Script.
- I would love to do this using regular expression. If so, please show me how to get Google Sheets to read strings A and B in cells and return true/false when the condition above is met.

Comment: A common way of doing that is to create arrays `a` and `b` that respectively contain all the characters in `A` and `B`, then check whether `b - a` is an empty array, where `-` is the set-difference method/function, the  characters in `b` that are not in `a` . For example, `[1,2,1,4,3,4,1] - [1,2,3] #=> [4, 4]`, because `4` is in `b` but not `a`. Similarly, `[1,2,1,4,3,4,1] - [1,2,3,4] #=> []` shows that all characters in `b` are in `a`.

Comment: Thank you very much, @CarySwoveland.  Can you show me an example of how you do this in Google Sheets please?  See the alternative answer below.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have that level of proficiency with Google Sheets. My comment was a general one.

Comment: OK.  Thank you, @CarySwoveland.  I will try it in Google Sheets and summarize here once I figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=arrayformula(sum(--REGEXMATCH(B1,split(REGEXREPLACE($A$1,"(.)","$1~"),"~"))))=len(B1)
```

[image]

### explanation

- `REGEXREPLACE($A$1,"(.)","$1~")` will add a tilde after each character
- then split the result by `~`
- compare with `REGEXMATCH(B1,split(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.)","$1~"),"~"))`
- then sum (`--` will tranform boolean to number) and compare with the length of A1

### extension

to avoid any repetition, try

```
=arrayformula(sum(--REGEXMATCH(B1,unique(transpose(split(REGEXREPLACE($A$1,"(.)","$1~"),"~"))))))=len(join("",unique(transpose(split(REGEXREPLACE(B1,"(.)","$1~"),"~")))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, @Mike, for the solution and explanation.  I will definitely try this solution today.

Comment: I tried this solution, Mike, and it worked.  The logic around repeated characters is awesome.  Thank you so much.  This answer saved me a lot of time trying to get it to work.  I hope it helps others facing the same challenge.